# Twython get Tweet using the ID

Tags: python, django, twitter, get, twython

Using [Twython](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython), how  do I get a single tweet using just the tweet ID_STR?

I know I can call it like this ([TwitterDocuentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/show/%3Aid))

```
"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show.json?id=112652479837110273"
```

but I keep running into return code 400 errors when attempting to call it in twython with the request() method. I was trying to do something similar to calling the showStatus endpoint

```
 tweet = twitter.request(endpoint='showStatus')
```

but that doesn't seem to let me plugin the ID_STR param (or I'm just plainly doing it wrong)

```
 tweet = twitter.request(endpoint='showStatus',
              params={id:'112652479837110273'})
```

How can I do this with just the tweet ID and [Twython](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython)?

Comment: Thank you! I haven't had a chance to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to do it:

```
status = twitter.showStatus(id="112652479837110273")
print status['text']
```

with the result:

`@twitter meets @seepicturely at #tcdisrupt cc.@boscomonkey @episod http://t.co/6J2EgYM`

Comment: Are you saying id takes a string as argument? I have sen this ERROR: exception: Twitter API returned a 400 (Bad Request), An error occurred processing your request. For type <type ‘str’> of course. Is this currently working in Twython? (btw: in the Twython API it is show_status)

Answer (score 3):

Twython doesn't have showStatus method , it should be (show_status)

```
status = twitter.show_status(id="112652479837110273")
```

Ref: https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/blob/master/tests/test_core.py line 147

Answer (score 1):

If you are still trying to do this here in 2014, the code now is:

```
twitter.statuses.show(id="126415614616154112")
```

If that doesn't work, check on: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/show/%3Aid 
Twitter keeps updating their API.